# vertica jdbc connection failover

Tags: jdbc, failover, vertica

I am using vertica 7.0 version and trying to add backupserver nodes during a connection failover. I tried to perform the similar steps as specified in the vertica 7.0 API programmer's guide. But I receive an error stating unknown host.

I am using this as the connection string : jdbc:vertica://badHostName:5433/dbName?connectionloadbalance=true

**A bad host name: **
If my current host name is xyz.abc.com then the bad host name I have mentioned as xyz.abc.comz.

Please let me know how to get through this.

Thanks

Comment: If I read this correctly, you want to add node names to your connection string. I see you're using JDBC. Can we see what you're connection string looks like?

Comment: I do not want to add node names to my string. I want my jdbc connection to point to a different node if the current node is down. For which I want to use the backup list feature provided by vertica jdbc.

Comment: I have updated the post too with details about the connection string.

Comment: It is working on my local machine now.. :) had added a wrong version of vertica jdk which I assume was not compatible for the new feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had added a wrong version of vertica jdk which I assume was not compatible for the new feature. So do check in your versions for such errors :)